# Sending message confirming bot have deleted/cleared messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm creating a clear command, and I want the bot after clearing confirming that it has cleared the messages.

My code :

```
@client.command(aliases=["del","delete","cl","clearmessages","deletemessages","deletemessage","clearmessage","cm"])
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
  if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
      await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    msg = await ctx.send(f"{amount} messages have been deleted!")
    import asyncio
    asyncio.sleep(15)
    await msg.delete()
  else:
    await ctx.send("Your don't have manage messages perms!")
```

I also want the bot to delete its own message after some time

Comment: msg.delete() has a delay argument. But this should work too although I find importing inside function weird. Use imports at top of the file unless you have a specific reason for it.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what the problem is ? What error do you get, what happens and what should happen ? Also, there is a keyword of `delete_after` in the `send()` function that you can use to auto-delete the message after n-seconds. [Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=send#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)

Comment: it just doesnt work when i use the command, try to run it for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to write this command would be:

```
@client.command(aliases=['put alternative names here'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
        await ctx.send(f"{amount} messages have been deleted!", delete_after=5)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Your don't have manage messages perms!")
```

Note - you will need the follow import statement:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Edit: You can get rid of the try, except loop and use the error handler instead

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    error = getattr(error, 'original', error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the required perms to carry out this command")
```

If you want it to be command specific so that you can add unique error messages:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    error = getattr(error, 'original', error)
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        if ctx.command.name == "clear":
            await ctx.send("You don't have manage messages perm")
```

Edit #2: Adding a limit

```
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    if amount <= 500:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
        await ctx.send(f"{amount} messages have been deleted!", delete_after=5)
    else:
        #error message
```

Comment: it works, but it wont tell me if you do have manage messages perms.

Comment: oh my bad, you will have to handle that specific error with an error handler

Comment: thanks! now it works, btw do you know how to make a limit for the command? (the limit for the amount) if you dont know ill just make another discussion

Comment: yea sure, you can check edit #2 (I have taken 500 only as an example, you can change that value)